# get the max element in alphanumeric array php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, max, element

I want the alphanumeric array below to return the max element depending on the value in the array which is `h5-19`: I tried using `max($array)`, but that returns `h5-9`.

```
Array
(
    [3] => h5-1
    [4] => h5-2
    [2] => h5-3
    [1] => h5-4
    [0] => h5-6
    [5] => h5-7
    [6] => h5-8
    [7] => h5-9
    [8] => h5-10
    [9] => h5-11
    [10] => h5-13
    [11] => h5-15
    [12] => h5-19
)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it always h5 or can it be T1 or something?

Comment: Or more specifically, is the pre-dash value always the same within the instance of the array, regardless of what that value actually is.

Comment: OP is not responding, close voted on unclear since there is not enough information in the question to create a complete answer in my opinion.

Comment: As already noted you can use [usort()](http://php.net/usort) to implement any conceivable sort algorithm but you first need to talk to your client and make sure you both understand what the rules are. For instance, would `g5-20` come before or after `h5-19`?

Comment: @Andreas , It is just "h5-" always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) sort array based on second digit of items. In sort function use [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to get target digit.

```
$originArr = [
    "h5-01",
    "h6-1",
    "h5-2",
    "h5-3",
    "h5-7",
    "h5-9",
    "h5-11",
    "h5-15",
    "h5-19" 
];
```

```
// Copy array to keep order of origin array
$arr = $originArr;
usort($arr, function($a, $b){
    return explode('-', $b)[1] - explode('-', $a)[1];
});
echo $arr[0];
// h5-19
```

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/VlOs0)

Comment: Can you change or omit `h5-01` because the current code would interpret it as an octal representation while doing conversion? Also, `second digit of items` is misleading. Can you change that to something else?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php


$set = array();

$data = array(
            '3' => 'h5-1',
            '4' => 'h5-2',
            '2' => 'h5-3',
            '1' => 'h5-4',
            '0' => 'h5-6',
            '5' => 'h5-7',
            '6' => 'h5-8',
            '7' => 'h5-9',
            '8' => 'h5-10',
            '9' => 'h5-11',
            '10' => 'h5-13',
            '11' => 'h5-15',
            '12' => 'h5-19',
            '789' => 'h1-8',
            '123' => 'p-78',
            '3000' => 'p-8',

        );

foreach($data as $each_element){
    $each_val = explode("-",$each_element);
    if(!isset($set[$each_val[0]])){
        $set[$each_val[0]] = intval($each_val[1]); 
    }
    $set[$each_val[0]] = max(intval($each_val[1]),$set[$each_val[0]]);
}

print_r($set);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [h5] => 19
    [h1] => 8
    [p] => 78
)
```

**Algorithm:**

- Create a set of tags which will be an associative array where `key` will be the tag name and it's `value` will be the max value of that tag present in your array.
- If the key is already set, get the max between the value in the key(tag) and the new value which also belongs to the same tag. This way you have max for each tag.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks, but can you let me know what bothers you about accuracy, so that I could correct it?

Comment: I'm not OP. I asked OP to clarify the question but there is no response yet.

Comment: @Andreas That way. Yes, I just wrote a solution from what I could get from what OP said. If she desires something else, I would amend my solution for sure :)

Comment: @vivek_23, thanks for the solution. It is perfect if my array had different values other than "h5-".

Comment: @ShraddhaBanerjee Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

This sorts the data use [`rsort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rsort.php) and `SORT_NATURAL` and then echos the first item...

```
$data = Array
(
    "3" => "h5-1",
    "4" => "h5-2",
    "2" => "h5-3",
    "1" => "h5-4",
    "11" => "h5-15",
    "12" => "h5-19"
    );

rsort($data, SORT_NATURAL);
echo $data[0];
```

which gives...

```
h5-19
```

Comment: It doesn't  sort correctly if array contain `h6-1` or `h5-01`

Comment: @Mohammad, tried adding `h6-1` to the above and the output is as I would expect `h6-1`.

Comment: **max element depending on the value in the array which is h5-19**. I think OP consider second digit in item as max

Comment: @Mohammad the max value in there array is `h5-19`, you don't know what OP wants to consider, or have you clarified this with them and it would be useful to add to the question.